# Recycling app pool each time a change has been made

Tags: .net, umbraco, application-pool

I've made a multi lingual site which contains 4 domains on the same site and thus, also 4 different languages and site trees.

However, each time I need to publich a new change to a site or otherwise (like updating a template, script etc.) I have to recycle the app pool to make the changes appear when viewing the site as a visitor.

How do I get about fixing this? Is it possible I have changed something for the worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to check are:

1. In /config/umbracoSettings.config check that this is true: `<ContinouslyUpdateXmlDiskCache>True</ContinouslyUpdateXmlDiskCache>`
2. If `<distributedCall enable="false">` is set to true, ensure that you have the current server in the list of servers.

If neither of these help, then it may be an IIS configuration issue. Please provide as much information as possible. Such as IIS version, Umbraco version etc as this may help identify where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

`<XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>True</XmlContentCheckForDiskChanges>` <-- This setting from umbracosettings.config file is set to False by default. 
By changing it to True, Umbraco updates the inmemory cache, if the xml file has changed.
That fixed our issues :)