# Recycling app pool each time something is published

Tags: .net, iis, lucene, umbraco, application-pool

I'm working on an Umbraco site where I have custom sections, and therefore use the application.config and trees.config files.

I have a problem where every time I publish something, the app pool recycles with the following message:

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 

_shutDownMessage=CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
CONFIG change
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown

_shutDownStack=   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.InitiateShutdownInternal()
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ShutdownAppDomain(String stackTrace)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnConfigChange(String message)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.OnStreamChanged(String streamname)
   at System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.FireNotifications()
   at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

_shutdownReason=ConfigurationChange
    DateTime=2015-06-17T13:01:24.0413457Z
```

I have tried setting the "Disable Recycling for Configuration Changes" option to true, but without any change. I guess this i because the app pool no longer recycles, but the app-domain still does.

[image: Advanced settings for my IIS app pool]

I have looked at this question, and even though the suggestions were good, it didn't help me. [Recycling app pool each time a change has been made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470714/recycling-app-pool-each-time-a-change-has-been-made)

I have some thoughts that it could be Umbraco that "writes" to application & trees.config as the timestamp on these are updated at the same time as I get the following message:

```
_shutdownReason=ConfigurationChange
```

As Eric Gaspard says it here at this issue "[applications.config & trees.config cannot be Read-only?](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5783#comment=67-18217)" umbraco opens these config files with write access. Maybe this could have some influence?

Additional info:

- Server is 2012

**Bottomline, my question is:**

Is there any way that I can either stop umbraco from touching the config files, or stop my app domain from recycling when the config files are changed?

Comment: Are you on Server 2012?

Comment: Yes I am, updating the question with that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with frequent app pool recycles when you update files in App_Data frequently (which Umbraco does). A MS HotFix was posted for it this morning: [see MS download here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3052480). It sounds like this might be the issue that you've been having.

Comment: It looks rather promising! :)
From what I can see, it actually solves the problem. I found the solution by myself before I saw your post, but your answer is correct, so I'll credit you :)